# How to fix amount sum issue in mysql decimal quantiy?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sum

I have two colums on mysql database table which holds float values. What I need is to get the sum of two colums and my mysql query is as follow

> `SELECT  amntGot,commission, SUM(amntGot+commission) as amt from mytable;`

Issue I got is the sum value goes wrong in the result
For example

> `amntGot = 4.6175`   `commission = 0.3825` Then amt goes to `4.999999821186066` . I expect result as 5 Which is (4.6175+0.3825)
> I dont know why the result gives me `4.999999821186066 instead of 5`

I could not find a dolution from StackOverflow, so any solution would be much appreciated,

I have attached screenshots of few results below

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the wild world of floating point math. Are these `FLOAT` columns or `DECIMAL`?

Comment: Yeah, a `SUM` on a single value is kind of pointless. The `SUM()` function is supposed to be used with an aggregator. It's not like Excel's `SUM()`.

Comment: @tadman I can't see how those results came from that query, hence I deleted the comment.

Comment: @Nick You're right in that the `SUM()` is out of place though.

Comment: You need to `ROUND` your results. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
SELECT  amntGot,commission, ROUND(SUM(amntGot+commission),0) as amt from mytable;
```